# Switch dll programmatically for MESA Software renderer

Tags: visual-studio, opengl, dll, mesa

I want to add the command-line option `--software-rendering` to my application which switches to the MESA opengl32.dll found in a subfolder (e.g. `mesa\opengl32.dll`). How can I switch to this dll programmatically?

So far I know that when I move the opengl32.dll to my main folder, the rendering uses this one, but I want it to be loaded depending on the command-line option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only clean solution is loading the `opengl32.dll` using `LoadLibrary` instead of linking it hard to your program. Then before calling `LoadLibrary` you can define the search path, where to look for the DLL, or even pass an absolute path. The downside is, that if using `LoadLibrary` every of the DLLs exported symbols must be retrieved manually using `GetProcAddress`. The good news is, that the GL loader generated by *[glLoadGen](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Home)* does exactly that; it uses `GetModuleHandle` to reference whatever `opengl32.dll` has been loaded into the process and uses `GetProcAddress` on the regular OpenGL functions. Furthermore it will also do all the extension loading as well.